# WordPress Плагин Telegram for WordPress не публикует новости на канале

Tags: php, wordpress

есть сайт на WP где автоматически добавляются посты пару раз в сутки, на самом сайте они отображаются сразу, но в Telegram они почему то не приходят, посты добавляю таким образом

```js
$post_data = array(
   'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags('{:en}'. $title .'{:}'),
   'post_content'  => '{:en}'. $content .'{:}',
   'post_status'   => 'publish',
   'post_type'      => 'post',
   'post_author'   => 3,
   'post_category' => array( 6 )
  );

  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
```

но если я захожу через админку и просто пересохраняю пост он сразу летит публикацией в Telegram, еще заметил что дополнительных полях для плагина отсутствует дата публикации, а после обновления она появляется, но при этом пост опубликован изначально[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу прошение за потраченное время, установил другой плагин (Autoposter (SNAP) ) и все норм заработало, может коме то пригодиться

Comment: Обратитесь к разработчикам плагина

Comment: Может быть я не правильно добавляю посты в базу или может у кого то тоже добавляются автоматом и работает с другим плагином

Comment: Плагин по любому цепляется к какому-то хуку, который срабатывает при добавлении поста через админку но не срабатывает у тебя. Смотри код плагина

Answer (score 0):

Дата публикации - это дата публикации в Telegram, судя по виду поля.

Раз пост создаётся, значит, делаете всё правильно. Да и код не вызывает сомнений. Есть предположение, что плагин реагирует только на обновление поста. Попробуйте добавить после `wp_insert_post()`

```
wp_update_post( $post_data );
```

Comment: не помогло к сожалению